# how to change from android asynctask to rxandroid?

Tags: android

I've been working with asynctask
But I can't use asynctask anymore

So I decided to use rxandroid and changed it as below
It seems to work, but I'm not sure if I'm using it properly
Could you give me any advice? Thank you

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    new AppTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,data[i]);
}
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    Observable observable = Observable.just(data);

    observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            //.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(observer);
}

Observer<String> observer = new Observer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String s) {
        process(s);

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To emit a consecutive range of integers, you can use Observable.range() . This will emit
each number from a start value and increment each emission until the specified count is
reached.

```
  Observable.range(1,10).subscribe(s -> System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + s));
```

output:

> ```
> RECEIVED:1
> RECEIVED:2
> RECEIVED:3
> RECEIVED:4
> RECEIVED:5
> RECEIVED:6
> RECEIVED:7
> RECEIVED:8
> RECEIVED:9
> RECEIVED:10
> ```

In your case, you can pass up to 10 items with `just`

```
Observable.just("one", "two", "three", ... ,"ten");
```

You can also use `Observable.fromIterable()` to emit the items from any Iterable type,
such as a `List` . It also will call `onNext()` for each element and then call `onComplete()`
after the iteration is complete.

`Schedulers.newThread()` may be helpful in cases where you want to create, use, and then destroy a thread
immediately so it does not take up memory. But for complex applications generally, you
will want to use Schedulers.io() so there is some attempt to reuse threads if possible.
You also have to be careful as Schedulers.newThread() can run amok in complex
applications (as can Schedulers.io() ) and create a high volume of threads, which could
crash your application.